# React Native Firebase Throwing Error when Map view is loaded

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-maps

Recently I started getting this warning in the console after adding the ios app to firebase project. Deleted and recreated all apps still not solving the issue of map loading

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Fetching the token failed: Please set your Project ID. A valid Firebase Project ID is required to communicate with Firebase server APIs: It identifies your application with Firebase.Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/init-options.]
at \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at \node_modules\expo-modules-core\build\NativeModulesProxy.native.js:27:27 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at \node_modules\css-select\lib\compile.js:5:0 in 
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:86:13 in tryCatch
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:66:31 in 
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:86:13 in tryCatch
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:124:27 in invoke
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:148:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at \node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at \node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at \node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:147:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:152:154 in _invoke
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:238:57 in exports.async
at \node_modules\css-select\node_modules\domutils\lib\helpers.js:128:3 in exports.uniqueSort
at \node_modules\css-select\lib\compile.js:118:47 in compileRules
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:86:13 in tryCatch
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:66:31 in 
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:86:13 in tryCatch
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:124:27 in invoke
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:148:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at \node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at \node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at \node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:147:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:152:154 in _invoke
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:238:57 in exports.async
at \node_modules\css-select\lib\compile.js:103:17 in token.map$argument_0
at \node_modules\expo-notifications\build\scheduleNotificationAsync.js:182:12 in components.forEach$argument_0
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:86:13 in tryCatch
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:66:31 in 
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:86:13 in tryCatch
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:124:27 in invoke
at \node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:130:16 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at \node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at \node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
at \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:177:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:437:30 in callImmediates
at \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediates
at \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:132:6 in __guard$argument_0
at \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:131:4 in flushedQueue

Comment: Found the issue. had to uninstall the new expo go and install an older version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the promise handle first use async await or try catch in your code where you call the data. And then use console to track the error.
If you still got error after this, just lemme know i will help you fix the errors.
Thanks